# sapui5 how to display value over 100 percentage on radial chart

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to show percentage value on radial chart, but radial chart's percentage property only allow me to display value between 0 and 100.

How can I do this?

Comment: there are also properties total and fraction. I would try setting total as 100 and fraction as more than 100 (say 110), and not setting percentage. Just an idea to try and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAP does not allow values over 100% for **Radial Micro Charts**, you could try setting the value using `JQuery` and manipulating fraction and total to fit your case.

Using the charts unique id for the first chart `chartRadial1` to get it's  element.

**Update:**

Bare in mind that, depending on the layout of your view, the children might change and you would have to research more into `nth and children selectors` to make sure you are selecting the right one but for this example its the [svg's 6th child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

[image: Dev tools]

```js
var percent = $(".sapSuiteRMCFont");
percent.text("200%");
```

OR In Controller & View:

```js
press: function(oEvent) {
  var myVal = 150,
    myTotal = 200,
    actTotal = 100,
    newVal = (myVal * actTotal) / myTotal;
  this.getView().byId("chartRadial1").setPercentage(newVal);
  //with the given id in xml view, you can be certain only the text for chartRadial1 will change using child selector
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("div#__xmlview2--chartRadial1 > svg.sapSuiteRMC.sapSuiteRMCSizeResponsive.sapSuiteRMCNeutralTextColor :nth-child(6)").text(myVal + "%");
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
div#__xmlview2--chartRadial1>svg.sapSuiteRMC.sapSuiteRMCSizeResponsive.sapSuiteRMCNeutralTextColor :nth-child(6) {
  font-family: fantasy !important;
}

div#__xmlview2--chartRadial2>svg.sapSuiteRMC.sapSuiteRMCSizeResponsive.sapSuiteRMCNeutralTextColor :nth-child(6) {
  font-family: arial !important;
}
```

```html
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="sap.sample.Detail" xmlns:semantic="sap.m.semantic" xmlns:c="sap.suite.ui.microchart">
  <content>
    <Label text="6.25rem x 6.25rem" width="12.5rem" class="sapUiSmallMargin" />
    <FlexBox width="6.25rem" height="6.25rem">
      <items>
        <c:RadialMicroChart id="chartRadial1" size="Responsive" percentage="99" press="press"></c:RadialMicroChart>
      </items>
    </FlexBox>
    <FlexBox width="6.25rem" height="6.25rem">
      <items>
        <c:RadialMicroChart id="chartRadial2" size="Responsive" percentage="99" press="press"></c:RadialMicroChart>
      </items>
    </FlexBox>
  </content>
</mvc:View>
```

Comment: Hi Olayinka, 

Thanks for your answer, you are right I could change percentage value by using your recommend. But the real problem is that I have more than one Radial Micro Chart.So if I change the class property all radial micro charts change in the same time.

What can I do for this situation ?

Comment: I have solved thanks to your helps :) I appreciated.

Comment: I am very junior, I have only two points on stackoverflow, If I reach the 15 points, I will also point you :)

Comment: @Basar 5 to go :)

Comment: Thanks :) @ Olayinka

Answer (score 2):

Having a view with `id__xmlview0`,
and a chart with id `RadialMicroChart1`:

```
$("#__xmlview0--RadialMicroChart1 > svg > text").text(yourText)
```

It will work even if you have several charts.